# Is there any way to capture item count into a variable when using Get-ChildItem?

Tags: powershell

I am using `Get-ChildItem` with say Remove-Item

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $myPath ... -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force
```

**Question**

I would like to capture the processed item's count into a variable, and use it for later. Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: Thx.  This is an answer

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh Would you mind adding it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this -

```
$count = 0; 
Get-ChildItem -Path $myPath ... -Recurse | % { 
    Remove-Item $_ -Force;
    $count++
}
```